# A loop issue and how to select closest values from given values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using two loops to do some calculations.

However I cannot get the expected result.

Below is my question.

```
Calculation = []
Result= []

my_data = [1.2, 3, 5, 9, 13, 15, 17, 19]

for Ele in my_data:
    for i in range(3,16,3):
        #print i  # Here I get 3, 6, 9, 12, 15
```

I want to get the values from my_data which are the closest values in range. So the result will be 3, 5 (closest to 6), 9, 13 (closest to 12), 15. Five values I will see in the result.

Then I do some calculations to get these five numbers.

```
        CutPoint = int(round(abs(float(Ele) - i)))
```

I used each element to minus each value in range, the smallest value will be the closest one.

```
        Calculation.append(CutPoint)

        if float(Ele) ==  i + min(Calculation): # Then I stuck here. Here is not entire correct. 
            TargetKey = str(Ele) # ps. Each element in my_data is just a key in my completed code. I will use this line to collect the data I need.
            Result.append(TargetKey)
print Result
```

I only can see ['3', '9', '15'] in my result. 5 and 13 are disappear.

I stuck here and do not know how to solve this issue.

Does anyone can help? Or a smarter way to achieve the same thing?

Thanks for help.

Comment: if you know that `my_data` is always sorted, you can do a mocked up binary search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `my_data` is not sorted, you could sort by the difference between your number and all the numbers in `my_data`, and take the N closest elements:

```
def closest(data, num, n):
    return sorted(data, key=lambda x: abs(x - num))[:n]
```

This however is very naive as it has to sort everytime you ask for a set of numbers. A better solution would be sorting the elements first, and then performing some sort of binary search as pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant way!